# How can I add contact component in Angular app

Tags: angular

I have already built the web site with 2 component which is Home and About and everything works fine, but if I try to add the third component on the same way like the component About my site does not work- I see this message from angular:     `Loading AppComponent content here ...`

I suppose there is some failure in my NG Module- I'm not sure thjis is correct one:

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';
import { navComponent } from './nav/app.navComponent';
import { contentAreaComponent } from './contentArea/app.contentAreaComponent';
import { footerComponent } from './footer/app.footerComponent';
import { aboutComponent } from './About/app.aboutComponent';
import { contactComponent } from './contact/app.contactComponent';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,
             RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
    path:'about',
    component:aboutComponent
    },
    {
    path:'contact',
    component:contactComponent
    },
    {
    path:'',
    component:contentAreaComponent
    }
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ,
                      headerComponent,
                      navComponent,
                      contentAreaComponent,
                      footerComponent,
                      aboutComponent,
                      contactComponent
                  ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: No trouble here, can you show the template and the component contact ?

Comment: Here is contactComponent.ts `Import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  // selector: 'footer',
  templateUrl: './contact.html',
})
export class contactComponent  { }`

Comment: can you show us the code of your template *contact.html* ?

Comment: Yes here you have: `<section class="main">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<div class="content">

123

</div>


</section>`

Comment: @leccepen would you mind add our code to https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @Tony Ngo, thank you for your idea, I have already overwritten the project in stackblitz and the code is working there and on my computer (with eclipse) not. No idea why but I will find it. Maybe it's only some typing error, but the code for component is fine. Thank you to all for your help.